# Spring Declarative Transcation and AOP

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-aop

we have decided to use spring for declaratively transcation management in our application.We are using hibernate (Independently not spring template approach) for the persistance layer but want to use spring's power to manage transcation demarcations.

I was going though Spring refrence material to get an idea about the Transcation management,since its using AOP for managing the things.I just get an basic ideas about the pointcuts and its expressions but not a complete or deep understanding of Spring's AOP.

My question is how much one need to know about the AOP in order to use spring's Transcation managment,since what i understood is the only thing matters in the transcations is the pointcut expression.

any help/suggestion will be much appriciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know that much beyond pointcuts.  Spring makes it relatively easy for you.  A deep understanding is not required.  They use Spring AOP, not AspectJ, which is more powerful and complex.

Comment: What you said it giving me the idea that since i have basic idea about pointcuts as well the other concepts so need not to go furthur and can go ahead with transcation API analysis